# how to implement Password Validation in android

Tags: java, android, validation, android-studio, passwords

i want to add a **Password Validation** on this, but getting problem in getting it, i want a **password pattern** which includes atleast some 
(`number of characters, special characters, lowercase letters, uppercase letters`)
this kind of pattern. But i am unable to achive this, please help.

**i am using android studio**

```
public class SignUp extends MainActivity {
    private EditText et_name, et_email, et_password, et_cpassword;
    private String name, email, password, cpassword;
    Button signupbtn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_up_form);
    et_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    et_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
    et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
    et_cpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Confirm_Password);
    signupbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Signbtn);
    signupbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            register();
        }
    });
}

public void register() {
    initialise();
    if (!validate()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sign up Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        onSignUpSuccess();
    }
}

public void onSignUpSuccess() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, HomePage.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

public boolean validate() {
    boolean valid = true;
    if (name.isEmpty() || name.length() > 32) {
        et_name.setError("please enter valid name");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (email.isEmpty() || !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        et_email.setError("please enter valid Email");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (password.isEmpty() )
        et_password.setError("please enter a valid password");
    return valid;
}
public void initialise(){
    name = et_name.getText().toString().trim();
    email = et_email.getText().toString().trim();
    password = et_password.getText().toString().trim();
    cpassword = et_cpassword.getText().toString().trim();
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure if both of these options help, but take a look a those: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/ (like events in JS) and https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html

Comment: Getting data realtime with initial thoughts would need an XMLHTTP Request, doing this with vanilla javascript can be problematic as each browser has it's own ''idea'' of how to make XMLHTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use polling.
So actually you can set up an interval through JavaScript and inside that interval start AJAX request to your server in order to get the data, and if needed because the data has changed, just refresh your table.
So something like this in JS:

```
// interval of one minute
setInterval(function() {
  // starts the AJAX request
  // get the response
 // if something has changed, update the table
}, 60 * 1000);
```

Even if this is the easiest way, it's actually not the best one because you will have a function which will always start requests to your server, even when nothing is happened.

The best solution is to setup Web Sockets and receive notifications directly from the server when some data has changed.

It seems that you have also something already done with django, but I am not an expert on it, so maybe you may look at this article:

https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django